# Combining Pickle files to make one big NLTK classifier

Tags: python, optimization, nltk

I know how to simply make and load one pickle file, what I want to do is:
Have one NLTK naive bayes classifier, that is made from multiple pickle files. Is this possible? I want to know how to make a pickle file out of the classifier, and then append more things learned from other training data so that I have one bigger pickle file.

The main reason is that while it takes my laptop about 2 minutes to train a classifier on about 3500 articles, it takes waaay too long for it to make one big pickle file out of that classifier. I think it's because it's taking up more than 90% of my RAM at that point and I was hoping I could sort of divide and conquer so it's not taking all my RAM at once. Or is there a better way to train off a large number of documents? Will I have to implement my own classifier or pickle-like file to do this? Or is there a way to accomplish this?

I've tried use del() on some variables that I stopped using before pickling but that hardly freed up the amount of RAM those variables took up.

I'm using python 2.7 with Anaconoda on windows 8 64 bit.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look into [joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/). It deals with large data quite well, especially when it's in Numpy format.

Comment: @JimmyC thanks! I've never done parallel programming before, but I guess I'll need to start! It's not exactly what I was looking for, I was just looking to how to combine classifiers, even if I don't have to do it parrallel, but I'll look into it.

Comment: @JimmyC can files created with joblib.dump() be appended to? Or is the object split into seperate files so that too much memory isn't being used all at once while making them? Because that was my main problem with the pickle files, that it would take up all my RAM and become very slow... Also, I'm not using numpy really, just nltk, so is it still really more beneficial compared to the python pickler?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your problem. Maybe what you are really looking for is an online classifier, which can be partially trained without keeping all of the training data in memory, and from my quick glance this isn't anything NLTK seems to offer. Would you consider looking into scikit-learn? [Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html) is an online Naive Bayes implementation. You're looking for the `partial_fit` method.

Comment: @JimmyC Thanks! That's exactly what I needed! If you put it as an answer I'll mark it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might be looking for is an online classifier, which can be partially trained without keeping all of the training data in memory, and from my quick glance this isn't anything NLTK seems to offer. Instead, I would recommend one of the classifiers in scikit-learn which has the `partial_fit` method implemented, [like this Naive Bayes classifier for multimodial models](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html).